# Can I Mask My Device Width?

Tags: css, media-queries

I'm using media types to specify certain styles for certain devices. However I'd like to use Chrome's element inspection to debug something I'm getting on mobile. Is there any way to specify my own device size to debug this?

Comment: There's [Resolution Test](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/idhfcdbheobinplaamokffboaccidbal), there's probably several others, including ones which impersonate specific browsers (mobile or otherwise). Also, doesn't [PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/) do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do it.
Use Chrome Webinspector to override device metrics.

[image: Using Chrome Webinspector to override device metrics]